# WPF: What is "ProjectName".App? Where is it defined? How do i rename?

Tags: c#, wpf, namespaces

a quick question that probably shouldnt need a stackoverflow question, but since i do not know the terminology i do not know what to google (tried but did not find the answear to my question).

At the top of your App.xaml file it says

```
<Application x:Class="XXXXX.App" //where XXXXX is name of project at creation
```

I changed the name of my project and solution, yet the old name for my project remains at this row. If i change it to the new name it gives me error. If i search for XXXXX with the find function the only location that comes up is that row in App.xaml. So is XXXXX.App defined somewhere else outside of the files in your project?

So, my questions are, where is XXXXX.App defined? How do i change the name? What does this line actually do? What is it referencing? Should i have a file called "XXXXX.App" somewhere on my computer?

[image: Find doesnt find anything but that row]

Comment: That first line is the XAML equivalent of `namespace WpfAppWinTest { public class App : Application { ... } }`. If you change the root namespace of your project, VS isn't smart enough to update your XAML files - you'll need to do this yourself, annoyingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"WpfAppWinTest" refers to the default namespace of your application.

Look under Project->Properties->Default namespace in Visual Studio:

[image]

To change the namespace of the already generated files, you could replace `namespace WpfAppWinTest` in your source files and `x:Class="WpfAppWinTest` in your XAML markup files.

Or create a new project with the better default name namespace.